# Apache Isis Security login No password encryption service is installed

Tags: isis

I'm new to Apache Isis, after I implemented Security Module, I try to login using `isis-module-security-admin` and `pass`. When I login I received this exception

> 11:38:48,577  [Native               qtp1881129850-19 DEBUG]  SELECT 'org.isisaddons.module.security.dom.user.ApplicationUser' AS "NUCLEUS_TYPE","A0"."accountType","A0"."atPath","A0"."emailAddress","A0"."encryptedPassword","A0"."familyName","A0"."faxNumber","A0"."givenName","A0"."knownAs","A0"."phoneNumber","A0"."status","A0"."username","A0"."id","A0"."version" FROM "isissecurity"."ApplicationUser" "A0" WHERE "A0"."username" = <'isis-module-security-admin'>
>   11:38:48,590  [Native               qtp1881129850-19 DEBUG]  SELECT 'org.isisaddons.module.security.dom.role.ApplicationRole' AS "NUCLEUS_TYPE","A1"."description","A1"."name","A1"."id" FROM "isissecurity"."ApplicationUserRoles" "A0" INNER JOIN "isissecurity"."ApplicationRole" "A1" ON "A0"."roleId" = "A1"."id" WHERE "A0"."userId" = <0>
>   11:38:48,599  [Native               qtp1881129850-19 DEBUG]  SELECT DISTINCT 'org.isisaddons.module.security.dom.permission.ApplicationPermission' AS "NUCLEUS_TYPE","A0"."featureFqn","A0"."featureType","A0"."mode","A0"."rule","A0"."id","A0"."version" FROM "isissecurity"."ApplicationPermission" "A0" CROSS JOIN "isissecurity"."ApplicationUser" "VAR_u" INNER JOIN "isissecurity"."ApplicationUserRoles" "C0" ON "VAR_u"."id" = "C0"."userId" INNER JOIN "isissecurity"."ApplicationRole" "D0" ON "C0"."roleId" = "D0"."id" WHERE "D0"."id" = "A0"."roleId" AND "VAR_u"."username" = <'isis-module-security-admin'>
>   11:38:48,614  [ShiroAuthenticatorOrAuthorizor qtp1881129850-19 ERROR]  Unable to authenticate
>   org.apache.shiro.authc.AuthenticationException: No password encryption service is installed

It look like I did not install Password encryption service. but I already add it into my pom.xml. What else should I do?

I try to override `getAdditionalServices`, but it's error `Can't override, method is final`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which version of Apache Isis?

If 1.15.x, then the incode platform's quickstart archetype shows the configuration in the AppManifest,  see [here](https://github.com/incodehq/incode-platform/blob/69b138dc8fc0572471bfebb6ca9a027d4e5b3878/ex/app/quickstart/appdefn/src/main/java/domainapp/appdefn/DomainAppAppManifestAbstract.java#L25)

Comment: Yes, I'm using 1.15.1. Why this doesn't exist on documentation. on doc recommend to override getAdditionalServices() instead, and it not override able. Your answer is work!!! thank so much

Comment: I guess the documentation you are referring to was written prior to 1.15.x.  In 1.15.x we introduced the AppManifestAbstract and its builder to simplify setup - AppManifest itself is just an interface.  If you can point me to the documentation that's you read that's out of date, I'll correct it (or even better, submit a pull request on it yourself).  Thx

Comment: I've updated the docs I think you were referring to, see [here](http://platform.incode.org/modules/spi/security/spi-security.html#_bootstrapping).